# With PowerShell's Get-ChildItem, how to I list matching files AND count them at the same time

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

How do I show AND count matching files using a single Get-ChildItem command in PowerShell?  Currently I am using two Get-ChildItem commands, the first to count, the second to display the files - works fine but it is not very effective when scanning an entire disk ...

Command to count the matches:
`$count = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchLocation -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}`

Command to display the files:
`Get-ChildItem -Path $searchLocation -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{$_.FullName}`

Comment: Simply store all matches in a variable `$t = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchLocation -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; $t.Count; $t.FullName`

Answer (score 1):

As `Get-ChildItem` is returning an array, its size is stored in `.Length` member and explicit measurement is not needed. Thus, store the file names in the same collection and then print length for number of entries and iterate the collection for file names. Swapping the variable name as `$files` to reflect this like so,

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchLocation -Filter $filename `
  -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
# ` can used to divide command into multiple lines (and work-around for markup stupidness)

# prints the number of items
$files.Length

# prints the full names
$files | %{$_.FullName}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to add a file number to each file as it processes.

```
$i = 1
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchLocation -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Foreach($Item in $Files) {
    $Item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileNo -Value $i
    $i++
}
$Files  | Select-Object FileNo, Fullname
```

You can then see the order the files were processed, get the last file number by doing `$File[-1].FileNo`. And it will maintain all the additional file metadata suck as `CreationTime`, `DirectoryName`, `VersionInfo` etc.

Comment: Its the same solution of me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this :

```
$AllFile=Get-ChildItem $searchLocation -File -Filter $filename -Recurse | select FullName
$AllFile.Count
$AllFile.FullName
```

Or you can ad a rank into your loop like this :

```
$Rang=0
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -File -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse | %{
$Rang++ 
Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Name "Rang" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $rang 
$_
} | select Rang, FullName
```